# How to Delete and Append Data (Truncate table) in PostgreSQL Table remotely by command line?

Tags: postgresql, cmd, command-line, psql

I'm working with a PostgreSQL Database, and I'm a little bit new on this. I need to load data to a specific table, and in order to keep this table updated I need to load the data from a CSV file every day.

By now I got a command line capable to copy the data from the CSV file to the table, here is my try:

```
psql -h suggestedorder.postgres.database.azure.com -d DataAnalytics -U dev_ext@suggestedorder -c "\copy planning.prueba (centro, almacen, fecha_carga)from 'C:\Users\geradiaz.MODELO\Desktop\Envase\Selección_Envase\Inputs\No_Seleccionado\o.csv' with delimiter as ','
```

But I need to truncate the table before to copy the new one data, **Do you know guys, how to delete the data/truncate the table in CMD by Command Line before to insert the new one data?**

Best regards guys and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
psql -c "TRUNCATE ..." -c "\copy ..."
```